# Html stop audio

Tags: html, audio

I have a simple website where audio automatically plays with

```
<embed src="how.mp3" autostart="true" loop="999" width="0" height="0">
</embed>
```

I have a pre existing button which starts a video. How do I get the music to stop when I click on the button which plays a video with

Answer (score 1):

You could simply remove the element from the DOM if you would not like the music to run anymore when the video is finished. Removing it means it will stop playing upon click. You'll need to get the ID of whatever the play button is of the video player you're using, and then edit the jquery below to have that ID. Below is an example with a random button that should trigger the DOM removal.

Something like this:

```
<embed id="music"src="how.mp3" autostart="true" loop="999" width="0" height="0">
</embed>

<a id="VideoButton">Click Me</a>

$("#VideoButton").click( function(){
   $("#music" ).remove();
}
```